# Heroku throws error where local host does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app running on heroku. Locally everything works fine. However, upon pushing to heroku there is an error.

The logs state this:

```
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:7:in `create'
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: ammo_id):
Started POST "/orders?ammo_id=4" for 96.235.177.110 at 2014-08-09 00:03:09 +0000
```

I.e. that this is an error in my `orders_controller` on line 7. This is line 7:

```
@order = @cart.orders.build(ammo_id:params[:ammo_id])
```

Locally this run perfectly. However, on heroku it does not. I changed that line to:

```
@order = @cart.orders.build(:ammo_id => params[:ammo_id])
```

And now it works on heroku. So my question is, why does the first syntax not work on heroku? Does it have to do with versions?

Comment: The disappearance of the error can't have anything to do with this syntax change.  Something else had to be wrong that was fixed by the second push.  The error is consistent with a database migration problem.

Comment: Sometimes you need to run $heroku restart , after migration.

Comment: You guys were right. Just happened to run some heroku migrations after that edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attributes**

Having just answered another question like this, I'd say the problem is almost certainly to do with **your Heroku DB not having the attributes it needs to run**

The issue here is that your Rails development DB & Heroku production DB will be completely different, and as such, you need to make sure you have migrated your Heroku db as you have your local one

The way to fix it will be to run the following on your local machine:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

--

Whenever Rails throws `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` - it means Rails does not have access to the particular `attribute` on your model class.

To understand this, you must remember that Rails is basically a series of `classes` which load with each request. These classes, as per the `object-orientated` structure, are populated by a series of *attributes*. These attributes, in the case of Rails, are pulled from the database -- meaning if your application cannot find specific attributes, it simply means the database doesn't have them

To fix this, you have to ensure you have the required columns present in your db. The most common instance of this issue is a lack of [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in your various models

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with Database Migrations. Make sure you run `heroku run rake db:migrate <your branch stuff here>` after every push so that our schema updates to your new models.

Also,Your heroku may be defaulting to an older version of ruby. The => syntax for hashes was the default in older versions of ruby. But now {key: value} is a new acceptable format. **Though this is very unlikely.**